# Is there a list of MPAA film numbers?

Tags: content-rating

At the end of most major American films, there's a number. I believe current films are running in the high 40,000s. From a little bit of research, [when the MPAA rates a film, they give it a unique number](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=51432).

I've found an [old list that seems to go up to 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202230803/http://members.chello.nl/%7Ea.degreef/Filmnummers.html), but I'm wondering if there's an official list online somewhere that shows every number.

I've been wondering for a while now if there'd be any friendly rivalry to grab number 50,000, which must be out soon.

Comment: Here's an archive.org link to the (now dead) link to the "up to 2010" list above  https://web.archive.org/web/20201202230803/http://members.chello.nl/~a.degreef/Filmnummers.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the list of cert. numbers assigned to films, both released and unreleased, but it's not really completed yet.

For the rated films, it's nearly complete, so the list is updated once a week, particularly on the day when the weekly rating bulletin comes out.

We have films that are not rated (modern era) and classics (released during the Production Code era from 1934 to 1968) with assigned numbers left. There are at least 23,000 NR (Not Rated) films out there, classics and NR films combined. Some examples of films not rated are *The Postcard Killings* (2020), *It's a Free World* (2008 and *The Water Babies* (1978). Because there are no inclusive and reliable sources related to cert. numbers available online, especially for those films that are not rated, purchasing those films is the only way to complete the list, sad to say.

- [Film numbers list.](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkV7u39L0ReghklppNLz_agdpDsk?e=2yolE9)

Comment: Did you compile this list?

Comment: Yes. I compiled the list.

Comment: Are you updating this list on an ongoing basis?

Comment: Yeah, particularly every week, when the weekly rating bulletin is issued. There are times that there may be delays in updating the list due to unforeseen circumstances.

Answer (score 8):

To my understanding, no one has *ever* compiled a list of every single film they've stuck the number on. I'm sure, buried in a database somewhere, the MPAA knows, but it doesn't appear to have been released.

The nearest I'm aware of is [this very eager fan](https://web.archive.org/web/20160306122441/http://fanedit.org/forums/archive/index.php/t-8598.html) who decided to research and list every film he could. It's still a work in progress, but all the numbers he has thus far can be found here: [50,000 movie challenge](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bxos_HwWGb9eVmx6RUJVMTQ5ZWs&usp=sharing) (link now dead).

Comment: Sadly; both the links are now broken :(.

Comment: There is an archived version of the thread @ https://web.archive.org/web/2016*/http://www.fanedit.org/forums/archive/index.php/t-8598.html .

Comment: The formatting on the above link didn't work; this may:     https://web.archive.org/web/20160306122441/http://fanedit.org/forums/archive/index.php/t-8598.html

Answer (score 5):

Richie's answer provides a relatively current list of titles with certificate numbers. Just to add to the answer: the [MPAA Website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association) has a **Related Links** section in the footer. One of those links points to [filmratings.com](https://www.filmratings.com/).

If you search through all ratings and lists, you can come up with a list. Here are some of the results. Notice how some of the certificate numbers are alphanumeric instead of just numeric.

```
Certificate Number,Name,Year,Rating,URL
52990,Boogie,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Boogie
52991,No Man's Land,2020,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=No+Man%27s+Land
52992,Vanguard,2020,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Vanguard
52993,Don't Tell A Soul,2020,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Don%27t+Tell+A+Soul
52994,Sir Alex Ferguson: Never Give In,2020,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Sir+Alex+Ferguson%3a+Never+Give+In
52996,Happily,2020,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Happily
52997,Crisis,2020,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Crisis
52998,Velvet Underground, The,2020,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Velvet+Underground%2c+The
52999,Rams,2020,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Rams
53001,Brothers By Blood,2020,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Brothers+By+Blood
53002,Next Goal Wins,2020,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Next+Goal+Wins
53003,DUNE,2020,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=DUNE
53004,Outside The Wire,2020,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Outside+The+Wire
53005,Tortured For Christ,2020,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Tortured+For+Christ
53006,Lamb,2020,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Lamb
53007,Starling, The,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Starling%2c+The
53008,Resurrection,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Resurrection
53009,Wildcat,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Wildcat
53010,Annette,2020,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Annette
53011,Lansky,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Lansky
53012,Pinocchio,2020,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Pinocchio
53013,Killing Of Two Lovers, The,2020,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Killing+Of+Two+Lovers%2c+The
53014,Max & Me,2020,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Max+%26+Me
53015,Locked Down,2020,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Locked+Down
53017,Six Minutes To Midnight,2020,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Six+Minutes+To+Midnight
53018,Justice Society: World War II,2020,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Justice+Society%3a+World+War+II
53019,Tomorrow War, The,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Tomorrow+War%2c+The
53020,Assault On VA-33,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Assault+On+VA-33
53021,Night Of The Sicario,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Night+Of+The+Sicario
53022,Freak Power: The Ballot Or The Bomb,2020,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Freak+Power%3a+The+Ballot+Or+The+Bomb
53023,Julia,2020,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Julia
53024,Falling,2020,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Falling
53025,Me You Madness,2020,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Me+You+Madness
53026,Every Breath You Take,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Every+Breath+You+Take
53027,Dara Of Jasenovac,2020,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Dara+Of+Jasenovac
53028,Phobias,2020,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Phobias
53030,Billie Eilish: The World's A Little Blurry,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Billie+Eilish%3a+The+World%27s+A+Little+Blurry
53031,Tyson's Run,2020,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Tyson%27s+Run
53032,Many Saints Of Newark, The ,2020,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Many+Saints+Of+Newark%2c+The+
53033,My Zoe,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=My+Zoe
53034,Tortured For Christ - Extended,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Tortured+For+Christ+-+Extended
53035,Tree, The,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Tree%2c+The
53036,Saving Sloane,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Saving+Sloane
53037,Final Account,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Final+Account
53039,Demon Slayer: Kimetsu No Yaiba â€“ The Movie: Mugen Train (Dubbed),2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Demon+Slayer%3a+Kimetsu+No+Yaiba+%e2%80%93+The+Movie%3a+Mugen+Train+(Dubbed)
53040,Demon Slayer: Kimetsu No Yaiba â€“ The Movie: Mugen Train (Subtitled),2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Demon+Slayer%3a+Kimetsu+No+Yaiba+%e2%80%93+The+Movie%3a+Mugen+Train+(Subtitled)
53046,Boss Baby: Family Business, The,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Boss+Baby%3a+Family+Business%2c+The
53047,Eddie,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Eddie
53048,COURAGEOUS LEGACY,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=COURAGEOUS+LEGACY
53049,Body Brokers,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Body+Brokers
53050,Gateway, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Gateway%2c+The
53051,Cinderella Story: Starstruck, A,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Cinderella+Story%3a+Starstruck%2c+A
53052,Zack Snyderâ€™s Justice League,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Zack+Snyder%e2%80%99s+Justice+League
53052,Zack Snyderâ€™s Justice League Justice Is Gray Edition,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Zack+Snyder%e2%80%99s+Justice+League+Justice+Is+Gray+Edition
53053,Army Of The Dead,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Army+Of+The+Dead
53054,Ice Road, The,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Ice+Road%2c+The
53055,Miss Willoughby And The Haunted Bookshop,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Miss+Willoughby+And+The+Haunted+Bookshop
53056,Misfits, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Misfits%2c+The
53057,Cruella,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Cruella
53058,Laureate, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Laureate%2c+The
53059,Trail Of Justice,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Trail+Of+Justice
53060,Mad Hatter, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Mad+Hatter%2c+The
53061,Blithe Spirit,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Blithe+Spirit
53062,PAW Patrol: The Movie,2021,G,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=PAW+Patrol%3a+The+Movie
53063,Diana: The Musical,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Diana%3a+The+Musical
53065,Batman: The Long Halloween Part One ,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Batman%3a+The+Long+Halloween+Part+One+
53066,Son Of The South,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Son+Of+The+South
53067,Songs Of Solomon,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Songs+Of+Solomon
53068,Percy Vs Goliath,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Percy+Vs+Goliath
53069,My Salinger Year,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=My+Salinger+Year
53070,Roe V Wade,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Roe+V+Wade
53071,Space Between, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Space+Between%2c+The
53072,Voyeurs, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Voyeurs%2c+The
53073,Toll, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Toll%2c+The
53074,Night Of The Kings,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Night+Of+The+Kings
53076,Limbo,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Limbo
53077,Walking With Herb,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Walking+With+Herb
53078,Together Together,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Together+Together
53079,SAS: Red Notice,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=SAS%3a+Red+Notice
53080,Seventh Day, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Seventh+Day%2c+The
53081,Flashback,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Flashback
53082,12 Mighty Orphans,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=12+Mighty+Orphans
53084,Locked In,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Locked+In
53085,Endangered Species,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Endangered+Species
53086,Queen Bees,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Queen+Bees
53087,Spirit Untamed,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Spirit+Untamed
53088,Girl Who Believes In Miracles, The,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Girl+Who+Believes+In+Miracles%2c+The
53089,American Eid,2021,G,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=American+Eid
53090,Let's Be Tigers,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Let%27s+Be+Tigers
53091,Nation Of Butterflies, The,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Nation+Of+Butterflies%2c+The
53092,Send It!,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Send+It!
53093,Last Call,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Last+Call
53094,Profile,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Profile
53095,Mortal Kombat,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Mortal+Kombat
53096,Passing,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Passing
53097,Loneliest Whale, The,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Loneliest+Whale%2c+The
53098,No Sudden Move,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=No+Sudden+Move
53101,Initiation,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Initiation
53102,Vanquish,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Vanquish
53104,Sparks Brothers, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Sparks+Brothers%2c+The
53105,Salvatore: Shoemaker Of Dreams,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Salvatore%3a+Shoemaker+Of+Dreams
53106,Duke, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Duke%2c+The
53107,Eyes Of Tammy Faye, The,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Eyes+Of+Tammy+Faye%2c+The
53108,Catch The Bullet,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Catch+The+Bullet
53109,Die In A Gunfight,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Die+In+A+Gunfight
53110,Four Good Days,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Four+Good+Days
53111,Summertime,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Summertime
53113,Joey & Ella,2021,G,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Joey+%26+Ella
53114,Felix And The Hidden Treasure,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Felix+And+The+Hidden+Treasure
53116,Summer Of Soul,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Summer+Of+Soul
53117,Pig,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Pig
53118,Snow Falls,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Snow+Falls
53119,Domino: Battle Of The Bones,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Domino%3a+Battle+Of+The+Bones
53122,Audible,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Audible
53124,Father Christmas Is Back,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Father+Christmas+Is+Back
53125,Jolt,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Jolt
53126,Till Death,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Till+Death
53128,Mary J Bligeâ€™s My Life,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Mary+J+Blige%e2%80%99s+My+Life
53129,Monday,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Monday
53130,New Order,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=New+Order
53131,In The Earth,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=In+The+Earth
53132,Rocky IV: 35th Anniversary Release,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Rocky+IV%3a+35th+Anniversary+Release
53134,Rita Moreno: Just A Girl Who Decided To Go For It,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Rita+Moreno%3a+Just+A+Girl+Who+Decided+To+Go+For+It
53135,Mainstream,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Mainstream
53136,Gunpowder Milkshake,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Gunpowder+Milkshake
53137,Sing 2,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Sing+2
53138,Cry Macho,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Cry+Macho
53139,House Next Door, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=House+Next+Door%2c+The
53140,Siberia,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Siberia
53141,Witnesses,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Witnesses
53142,Seaper Powers The Movie,2021,G,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Seaper+Powers+The+Movie
53144,Long Story Short,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Long+Story+Short
53145,Werewolves Within,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Werewolves+Within
53146,Street Gang: How We Got To Sesame Street,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Street+Gang%3a+How+We+Got+To+Sesame+Street
53147,Paper Tigers, The,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Paper+Tigers%2c+The
53149,Blush,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Blush
53150,Luca,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Luca
53151,Batman: The Long Halloween Part Two,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Batman%3a+The+Long+Halloween+Part+Two
53152,Butter,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Butter
53153,Triumph,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Triumph
53154,Smelliville,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Smelliville
53155,Skater Girl,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Skater+Girl
53157,Ace & The Christmas Miracle,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Ace+%26+The+Christmas+Miracle
53158,Forever Purge, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Forever+Purge%2c+The
53159,Port Authority,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Port+Authority
53161,Dry, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Dry%2c+The
53162,Djinn, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Djinn%2c+The
53163,Ape Star, The,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Ape+Star%2c+The
53164,KIPCHOGE: The Last Milestone,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=KIPCHOGE%3a+The+Last+Milestone
53166,Sweet Girl,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Sweet+Girl
53168,Narco Sub,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Narco+Sub
53170,Birds Of Paradise,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Birds+Of+Paradise
53171,Texas Chainsaw Massacre,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Texas+Chainsaw+Massacre
53172,Grace And Grit,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Grace+And+Grit
53174,Little Prince(ss), The,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Little+Prince(ss)%2c+The
53176,Separation,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Separation
53177,Mayor Pete,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Mayor+Pete
53178,Conjuring: The Devil Made Me Do It, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Conjuring%3a+The+Devil+Made+Me+Do+It%2c+The
53179,Gaia,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Gaia
53180,Here Today,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Here+Today
53181,Guilty, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Guilty%2c+The
53182,Mouthful Of Air, A,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Mouthful+Of+Air%2c+A
53183,Drama Drama,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Drama+Drama
53185,Disciples,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Disciples
53186,Show Me The Father,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Show+Me+The+Father
53188,Black Easter,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Black+Easter
53189,MEHAMOOD,2021,G,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=MEHAMOOD
53190,Night Of The Animated Dead,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Night+Of+The+Animated+Dead
53201,Notorious Nick,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Notorious+Nick
53202,Jockey,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Jockey
53203,Habit,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Habit
53205,Midnight In The Switchgrass,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Midnight+In+The+Switchgrass
53206,Fallout, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Fallout%2c+The
53209,Finch,2021,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Finch
53210,American Traitor: The Trial Of Axis Sally,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=American+Traitor%3a+The+Trial+Of+Axis+Sally
53213,Occupation: Rainfall,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Occupation%3a+Rainfall
53215,Don't Breathe 2,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Don%27t+Breathe+2
53217,HERO MODE,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=HERO+MODE
53220,Secret Agent Dingledorf And His Trusty Dog Splat,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Secret+Agent+Dingledorf+And+His+Trusty+Dog+Splat
53221,Hidden Life Of Trees, The,2021,PG,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Hidden+Life+Of+Trees%2c+The
53222,Life After,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Life+After
53225,Stillwater,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Stillwater
53226,Estate, The,2021,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Estate%2c+The
91772,Prize Winner Of Defiance, Ohio, The,2005,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Prize+Winner+Of+Defiance%2c+Ohio%2c+The
230047,Duster, The,1971,G,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Duster%2c+The
02245-R,Animal Crackers,1974,G,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Animal+Crackers
23778 - A,Aaron Loves Angela,1976,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Aaron+Loves+Angela
27495-A,Lethal,1985,PG-13,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Lethal
AA-101,Thin Air,1970,G,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Thin+Air
AA-102,Last Day Of The War, The,1970,GP,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Last+Day+Of+The+War%2c+The
AA-103,Kashmiri Run,1970,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Kashmiri+Run
AA-104,Four Rode Out,1970,R,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Four+Rode+Out
AA-105,Then Came Bronson,1970,GP,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Then+Came+Bronson
AA106,City Beneath The Sea,1971,G,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=City+Beneath+The+Sea
AA-108,Earth II,1971,G,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Earth+II
AA-1407,Operation Heartbeat,1971,G,http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Operation+Heartbeat
```

Answer (score 4):

MPPDA - MPAA - USA The Motion Picture Production Code film numbers to 52000 - - -

http://www.filmsonsuper8.com/censorship/mpaa-film-numbers-52000.html

http://www.filmsonsuper8.com/mpaa/mpaa-film-numbers-52000.html

includes USA films from 2010 to 2014

and also provides two excel spreadsheet versions for download

MPAA - excel worksheet filetype:xlsx for download - USA The Motion Picture Production Code film numbers to 52000 - - -

Comment: Lists seem to only go to 2010 (~46,000)? :/

Answer (score 3):

I compiled [a list](https://richienb.github.io/mpaa-list) of MPAA film numbers.

As it turns out, film 50000 doesn't actually exist. However, here are the surrounding items:

49998. [Steve Jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Jobs_(film))
49999. [Roger Waters: The Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Waters:_The_Wall)
50000. 
50001. [The Veil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Veil_(2016_film))
50002. [In a Valley of Violence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_a_Valley_of_Violence)

Comment: The film numbered 50000 points to an indie film called "Chloe and Theo".

Comment: filmratings.com doesn't list it, how did you find out?

Comment: It's known as "Chloe & Theo" there. No other titles were stated, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official list, but in the following site http://www.filmratings.com/ you can find the M.P.A.A. number

Comment: +1 This is not a list but it is the official upstream source. Search through partial title or just rating & release year to get the full title, rating, reason and the certificate number.

Comment: I think that is an official site, as it is linked from the MPAA website: https://www.motionpictures.org/.

Comment: That site is designed only for rated films from 1968 to the present. Months ago, I tried asking them to make that site inclusive by including films that are not rated with potential certificate numbers assigned.